# Blender rigid body Vehicle RIG error

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation, collision, rigidbody

I got into rigid body for simulation of vehicle suspension settings Blender 3.2). The first drop and collision works perfectly and damps properly

[image: Contact with ground]

But once the rig gets into movement (go down the hill for example) after few second of working perfectly it suddenly blasts in the air and all generic spring constraints break loose.

[image: The problem]

The images display connected carts, though this erratic result occurs also on the single cart.

All objects have applied scale of 1.0, rotation 0

The axes are set as *Generic Spring* constraint

- *Z Stiffness* $10$
- *Z Damping* $0.5$
- Simulation type Blender 2.7

Wheels:

- Default *Rigid Body*, $1 kg$
- *Shape* *Cylinder* (tried other also),
- *Friction* $1.0$

Body:

- Default *Rigid Body*, $10 kg$

Ground:

- Default *Rigid body*, *Passive*
- *Collision Shape* *Mesh*

Seems more like a bug in blender rather than bad settings, but I could be wrong. Anyone has experience with this behavior?

https://we.tl/t-7DoIpYfmie

[image: Initial setup]

Comment: if you could provide a blend file, i will gladly have a look

Comment: Sure, give it a try, thanks! https://we.tl/t-7DoIpYfmie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think (i tried it out and it worked) you have to do it like this:

[image]

You can of course define generic springs, but these are really just "springs" - they cannot rotate freely.

So you have to define a generic spring from the car (cube) to another object, which i call the "wheel holder" (this is the small cylinder).

And another generic constraint which takes care of the rotation, so it is the connection of the wheel holder to the wheel.

Settings like this:

Spring:

[image]

Wheel to wheel holder:

[image]

result:

[image]

if one vehicle works, just copy it and connect both cars with a generic spring:

[image]

video tutorial: https://youtu.be/7l4kRvKjbpE

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - actually the mentioned "wheel holder" was another step I wanted to take for rigging (to link brake calipers to) and it also improves the anim results. Great help! ;)

Comment: glad i could help

Comment: I would ask you for your insight again, since the rig is still making it's "dance" https://we.tl/t-rZFrIb0pCQ Could I ask you to take a look at that? I followed the tutorial to the letter, but at the end I can not reach your result.

Comment: I just tried to flip the rotation axis from X to Y (to rotate the wheels along their Y-axis) and everything works, very interesting. SOLVED.